# Need help on my javafx-css

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I have this problem in my `Java Eclipse` [image]

this happens when i add my `CSS File` to the Scene. And i really don't know what to do here

I have tried adding a `Source Folder` and inside the source folder is the `Css file` then adding it to like this `scene.getStyleSheets().add("Resource/Css/style.sheet"`

and this error is still showing can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file directly under src in Eclipse, you need to request it from there, not from a "Resource/Css" sub-folder.

Also, the filename is obviously style.css, not style.sheet.